# How do I add a quiet blower or fan to a gas fireplace?

Tags: vent, fireplace, installation, noise, blower

I have beautiful fireplace in my family room.  It is gas rather than wood burning, and it vents straight outside.

Due to the nature of how it is vented, I don't really get much heat from it, and I think I am losing a lot of the heat it could be generating during winter (and therefore wasting a lot of energy and increasing my cost.)

After reading my fireplace manual, it appears that I can install a blower that can move heated air from around the exhaust back into the room. There were no instructions on how to do so, however.

What would it take to install a blower for my fireplace, and where might I find a very quiet blower? The noise level is an important factor, as I've heard some fireplace blowers that are extremely noisy, and given the acoustics of the room, I worry it will drown out sound from the entertainment system.

Comment: I tried to use the tag 'blower', however it appears I don't have that right until I reach 150 rep? Could someone edit my post and add 'blower'? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would contact the manufacturer of the fireplace; either by phone or on the web, they should have a blower designed for your fireplace.  They may also provide instructions on hooking it up, or offer installation as a service.